# Variable assignment in python

Tags: python

I am calling a method on an object and I want the returned value to be assigned to the object itself. Is there a proper programming idiom for this?

The example I am using is this:

```
d = "2007-07-18 10:03:19"
d.split()[0]
```

However `split` doesn't change the original.

---

The other way:

```
d = d.split()[0]
```

Seems rather clunky. Is there a cleaner way or is this just the way it is?

Comment: That is just the way it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, you are using a string, which is immutable, so you can't mutate its value.

> Is there a proper programming idiom for this?

You are already using it, however to be more efficient you may use `d=d.split(None, 1)[0]` since you only need the first part, but what you are doing is sufficient anyway.

Comment: In a bit different scenario, `x=list(d)` and then working with x might be sensible. I think.